# How to change click event in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Its been few days over to me, learning Android App development :

I have created an APK which is having two buttons (largeButton & smallButton) if you click on these button test will large and small accordingly.

What i am trying to do :

When i click second time button should change in previous mode i.e Vice Versa should happen.

Here is my code :

**mainActivity:**

```
package com.firstapk.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


     Button largButton;
     Button smallButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        largButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.largbutton);
        smallButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.smallbutton);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);



        return true;
    }



    //public void getDisplay(View view){

         public void largebuttonclick(View view){
             try{

                 largButton.setTextSize(40);

             }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.d("TestApp", e.getMessage());
             }
         }
    //}

         public void smallButtonClick(View view){
             try{
                 smallButton.setTextSize(5);
             }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.d("TestApp",e.getMessage());
             }
         }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/largbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:onClick="largebuttonclick"
        android:text="@string/button_large" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/smallbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:onClick="smallButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/button_small" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did now it's right, if he click "Max size" he will see max size;

So maybe you want to use only one button which works like (+ and -)? If yes use one onClick and a boolean variable to save the current status (max size, small size).

```
private boolean maxSize; // false if small, true if max
public void onChangeSize(View view)
{
 if (maxSize)//max->small
 {
   smallButton.setTextSize(5);
 }
 else//small->max
 {
   largButton.setTextSize(40);
 }

 maxSize = !maxSize;
}
```

Then `android:onClick="onChangeSize"` in the two buttons xml.

You could use the same approch for your current code, but it will work in the same way.